# Local MATLAB GUI, remote filesystem

Tags: matlab, user-interface, ssh, cluster-computing

I run MATLAB2014b on an Ubuntu client and have ssh-based access (with passwordless ssh enabled) to multiple other computer clusters that have both data in the form of huge .mat files and MATLAB code on them. Because my local machine is very limited in terms of space, I cannot easily copy the files locally and work on them. Furthermore, those computer clusters have shared resources, so opening up a MATLAB GUI on the clusters (by doing ssh -X, for example) is going to cause issues to other researchers connected to those machines. Opening up a MATLAB session without a display is totally possible, but it lowers my productivity since the GUI is very helpful to me.

What I would ideally want is to use my local MATLAB GUI but access all the files and my code in the remote server. Please note that this is not the same as creating a cluster profile to submit parallel jobs to; for this particular - more complicated - piece of information, multiple tutorials exist.

Comment: I would like to know how to do the exact same thing. Although i just want to acces data and copy just what i need (which is usually many GB less)